# Ansible: как расчитать предел для исполняемой машины

Tags: сервер, ansible, железо, devops

Добрый вечер!

Постепенно перехожу на Ansible. Стоит задача расчитать оптималные параметры для исполняемой машины.

Не натыкался в документации на это.

Исходные данные:

- количество хостов: до 3000
- выходной канал: 2Гбит/с
- максимальный пинг до хоста: 5с
- максималное время даунтайма: 30мин
- максималное время на плейбук/роль для всех хостов: 30мин

Нужно подобрать:

- параметры станции: исходя из потребления памяти и процессора для Ansible
- оптимальные настройки:  количество соединений за раз, количество повторных пробегов для перехода всех хостов в желаемое состояне

Хосты НЕ облачные, железные в основном на Ubuntu 9, 12, 16.

Пробовал на рабочей машине до 50 подлючений за раз в случайном порядке, не померла.

Comment: Подозреваю, что только экспериментальным путем. Сильно зависит от используемых модулей.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Пока так и выходит. Продукт популярный вот только если нужна конкретика, в документации среди воды, сложно найти.

Comment: Могу попробовать на примерно сотне десктопов с виндой ну и с модулями win_*. Если не забуду протестить - отпишусь скока чего сожрало и хватило ли моего утюга для управления.

Comment: @donRumata Буду рад. Тоже как время будет свободное скину статистику, думаю будет полезно для вновь прибывших и пометку для себя оставлю.

Answer (score 1):

В общем сегодня запускал обновление libreoffice, firefox, google chrome и notepad++ на ~100 (точнее могу сказать после просмотра логов) win7-64 машинах.

Железо:

Celeron E1400, 1GB RAM, 40GB HDD, ubuntu 16.04.

Комп даже не заметил, что его как-то нагрузили. А вот сервер, с которого тянулись файлы - очень даже.

Comment: @don_Rumata Сейчас провожу тесты конфигурационного сценария для полной установки  от "чистой" системы до всего необходимого. Установка и обновление пакетов, создание пользователей, установка основных приложений (Java). Самая большая нагрузка идет на исполняемой машине при запуске модуля **copy** и ему подобных. Даже не большой файл (2мб) запрашиваемый 100 и более серверами, может заметно просадить систему. Рабочая станция: Supermicro 16GB RAM, i7, HDD (не SSD, наличие которого ослабит нагрузку при высоком i/o), Fedora 25

Comment: @Hellseher, ну я так понимаю, что файо у тебя тянется с того же компа с которого запускается ansible?

Comment: @Hellseher, поставил `forks = 50` и начал через `win_command` ставить `netbeans v8.2` на 125 машин. Выжрало 876 метров оперативы и 328 метра свапа.